# How to enable log rotation in QuestDB

Tags: questdb

How do I enable log rotation in QuestDB to avoid disk space issues? It looks like QuestDB logs are never rotated or deleted on their own. I could not find anything about log rotation in QuestDB documentation.

This is my current log.conf

```
# list of configured writers
writers=file,stdout,http.min

# file writer
w.file.class=io.questdb.log.LogFileWriter
w.file.location=questdb-docker.log
w.file.level=INFO,ERROR,DEBUG

# stdout
w.stdout.class=io.questdb.log.LogConsoleWriter
w.stdout.level=INFO

# min http server, used monitoring
w.http.min.class=io.questdb.log.LogConsoleWriter
w.http.min.level=ERROR
w.http.min.scope=http-min-server
```